# Identifying a "rotated shear" matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose that we're in $\Bbb R^n$. Then the simplest shear matrix can be described as

$$S_\lambda = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \lambda & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Where $\lambda$ is a free parameter that can be thought of as the "slope" of the shear.

This shear preserves the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace that is orthogonal to the vector $(0,1,0,...,0)$, and shears everything along the $(1,0,0,...,0)$-axis. I will call this the "canonical" shear basis.

If we would like to shear along a different axis and preserve a different $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace, that can be expressed via the following matrix product:

$$
OS_\lambda O^{-1}
$$

where $O$ is an arbitrary orthogonal matrix (which may have determinant $-1$). This can be thought of as rotating and/or reflecting our desired vector and subspace into the canonical basis, performing the shear, and then rotating back. I will call this a "rotated shear."

My question: given a "rotated shear" matrix, how can I identify it as such, and decompose it into the product $OS_\lambda O^{-1}$? Is there some easy way to identify the rotation, and the shear axes involved?

Or, put another way, is there a general matrix decomposition that will yield the desired form if I give it a rotated shear matrix (and will yield something else for any other general matrix)?

Comment: What can you say about the eigenvalues of $S$ and their eigenspace(s)?

Comment: All the eigenvalues are 1, and every vector with the second coordinate as 0 is an eigenvector. But, the matrix isn't diagonalizable...

Comment: All of your “rotated shears” are similar to this canonical shear, aren’t they?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know in advance what the $\lambda$ is.

Comment: All you need to know a priori is that $\lambda\ne0$, which you already know from the multiplicities of the eigenvalue. What’s the Jordan normal form of $S$?

Comment: The Jordan form will always be what I'm calling $S_1$, which is just a shear matrix with that same shape but with $\lambda=1$. So for $S_2$ with $\lambda=2$, for instance, the Jordan form is still the same matrix shape with $\lambda=1$, and then the similarity matrix taking from the original shear to it's Jordan form seems to be some strange anisotropic scaling.

Comment: If I know in advance that the matrix I am given is unitarily similar to some $S_\lambda$, I can get the exact value of $\lambda$ from the Frobenius norm of the matrix, which is unitary invariant. From there, there is probably a way to divide things to get the exact rotation involved. I don't know how to identify in advance, though, whether a transformation matrix is a rotated shear.

Comment: Re: the last paragraph, I think the [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) can do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $\ n\times n\ $ matrix $\ A\ $ is of the form 
$\ OS_\lambda O^{-1}\ $, with $\ O\ $ orthogonal and $\ \lambda\ne 0\ $, if and only if:

- The nullspace $\ \mathcal{N}_{A-I}\ $ of $\ A-I\ $ has dimension $\ n-1\ $; and
- $\ \left(A-I\right)^{\,2} = 0\ $.

For if $\ A=OS_\lambda O^{-1} $, then  $\ \mathcal{N}_{A-I}\ $ is the space spanned by the first and third to $\ n^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ columns of $\ O\ $, and $$\ \left(A-I\right)^{\,2} =O\left(S_\lambda -I\right)^2 O^{-1} =0\ .$$

Now suppose that $\ A\ $ satisfies the above two conditions. Then there exists a non-zero  $\ v\in \mathcal{N}_{A-I}^\top\ $, and since $\ v\not\in \mathcal{N}_{A-I}\ $ then $\ \left(A-I\right)v\ne 0\ $. But since $\ \left(A-I\right)^{\,2} = 0\ $ then $\ \left(A-I\right)v\in \mathcal{N}_{A-I}\ $, and so $\ Av =  v + \omega\ $ for some non-zero $\ \omega\in \mathcal{N}_{A-I}\ $. Thus, $\ A\frac{v}{||v||}=\frac{v}{||v||}+\left(\frac{||w||}{||v||}\right)\frac{w}{||w||}\ $.   Now if $\ \omega_1,\omega_2, \dots, \omega_n\ $ is any orthonormal basis with  $\ \omega_1= \frac{w}{||w||}\ $  and $\omega_2= \frac{v}{||v||}\ $, and $\ \Omega\ $ the matrix whose $\ j^{\,\mathrm{th}}\ $ column is $\ \omega_j\ $, then $\ \Omega^{-1}A\Omega=S_\lambda\ $, where $\ \lambda = \frac{||w||}{||v||}\ $.

Comment: This is very good! I wonder what can be said about the generalized matrices where the dimension of the null space is $n-k$ for some $k$, and where we have $(A-I)^r = 0$ for some $r$ that need not be 2?

Comment: If $\ \left(A-I\right)^{\,r}=0\ $ then the minimal polynomial of $\ A\ $ is $\ \left(x-I\right)^s\ $ for some $\ s=1,2,\dots,r\ $, which is the size of $\ A$'s  largest Jordan block. The dimension of the nullspace is the number of Jordan blocks.  Since the sizes of these have to sum to $\ n\ $, we would have to have $\ n-\frac{n}{s}\ge k\ge s-1\ $.  If $\ k=s-1\ $, then there would have to be one block of size $\ s\ $ and $\ n-s\ $ of size $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to understand the Jordan block in these terms - I can see that if I am just shearing one axis in one direction, the Jordan normal form will have exactly one $1$ on the superdiagonal somewhere. If the Jordan normal form has two $1$'s somewhere, does that mean there are two shears happening simultaneously? I have never seen the Jordan form related to shear matrices before.